# How to read generic xml using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am having  a generic xml which looks like below

```
 <Results>
  <Columns>
    <Column>Center ID</Column>
    <Column>Center Name</Column>
   /Columns>
  <Result>
    <Data>32452368</Data>
    <Data>Center1</Data>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <Data>32452368</Data>
    <Data> Center2</Data>
  </Result>

</Results>
```

I am trying use jquery to read the data from this xml.

```
 $(xml).find("Results/Result").each(function()
    {
    }
```

But i need to know some way ,to read them in order,like the first data in  is always Center ID.
Any suggestions...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var columns = [];

// Go through the first Result tag and record the order of the columns:
$(xml).find('Results > Result:first').each(function() {
    $(this).children('Data').each(function() {
        columns.push( $(this).text() );
    });
});

var results = [];
$(xml).find('Results > Result:not(:first)').each(function() {
    // Result will map column names to values:
    var result = {};
    $(this).children('Data').each(function(i) {
        result[ columns[i++] ] = $(this).text();
    });
    results.push(result);
});

// Now results is an array of objects:
// [
//   { 'Center ID': 32452368', 'Center Name': 'Center1' },
//   { 'Center ID': 32452368', 'Center Name': 'Center2' }
// ]
```

The only thing that had you off on the wrong track was use of `/` in your selector, which is not a valid CSS/jQuery selector. `>` is used to indicate a parent/child relationship. `Results > Result` is the key.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion .. i am in the process of implementing and will update the status once its done.Thanks

Comment: Is there any way i can get data Result:first,Result:second ,Result:third.. like that using jquery

Comment: Yes `:eq()` is the selector for that.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right side, `each` method iterates over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element in order, however the syntax of the selector in the `find` method is not correct, try this:

```
$(xml).find('Results > Result').each(function(){
   // do something here
})
```